# Static member function pointer as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I get this compile error with the latest VC++ compiler (Nov 2012 CTP) when using static member function pointer as template argument:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'wrapper<int (int,int),int A::f1(int,int)>'
```

But when using free function, everything works ok.
I looked up some similar bugs in g++( [pointer to static member function is "invalid" as a template argument for g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174920/pointer-to-static-member-function-is-invalid-as-a-template-argument-for-g) ), but there it explicitly states that argument is invalid. What is so different about static functions?

I'm casting the function to `void(*)(void)` because construct like `<typename T_Ret, typename... T_Args, T_Ret(*)(T_Args...)>` don't compile for some other urelated reasons.

```
struct A
{
    static int f1(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int f2(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template <typename Sig, void(*fnc)(void)>
struct wrapper;

template <void(*fnc)(void), typename T_Ret, typename... T_Args>
struct wrapper<T_Ret (T_Args...), fnc>
{
    static bool apply()
    {
        // get some ints here
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        typedef T_Ret (fnc_ptr*)(T_Args...);
        int res = ( (fnc_ptr)fnc )(a, b);
        // do smth with result
        res;
        return true;    // or false
    }
};

int main()
{
    bool res;
    res = wrapper<decltype(A::f1), (void(*)(void))A::f1>::apply();  // error
    res = wrapper<decltype(f2), (void(*)(void))f2>::apply();  // compiles ok
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Ok, I narrowed the issue to decltype.
When I write the type explicitly, everything works:

```
res = wrapper<int(int, int), (void(*)(void))A::f1>::apply();  // compiles ok
```

Comment: Are you casting functions?  I don't think you're allowed to do that.

Comment: You are allowed, as far as I know, as long as you cast it back to correct type before calling.

Comment: This is a simplification of your problem.  What is your real problem?

Comment: I'd like to use static class functions, so I don't have to declare free functions and then make them friends of the class (or make all class members public), but they don't work.

Comment: I just tried to do the same thing with pointer-to-member function, and got same error message.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I was just wrapping few class for use from lua, and wanted to reduce boilerplate a bit.

Comment: I guess I can't see why this approach is any better (or less boilerplatey) than `res = A::f1(a, b) == v;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Looks like it's a compiler bug: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/STLCCSeries6#c634886322325940618

Workaround:

Change `decltype(A::f1)` to `decltype(&A::f1)` which changed its output from `int(int, int)` to `int (__cdecl *)(int,int)`. And change

```
template <void(*fnc)(void), typename T_Ret, typename... T_Args>
struct wrapper<T_Ret (T_Args...), fnc>
```

to

```
template <void(*fnc)(void), typename T_Ret, typename... T_Args>
struct wrapper<T_Ret (*)(T_Args...), fnc>
```

Working code:

```
struct A
{
    static int f1(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

template <typename Sig, void(*fnc)(void)>
struct wrapper;

template <void(*fnc)(void), typename T_Ret, typename... T_Args>
struct wrapper<T_Ret (*)(T_Args...), fnc>
{
    static bool apply()
    {
        // get some ints here
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        typedef T_Ret (*fnc_ptr)(T_Args...);
        int res = ( (fnc_ptr)fnc )(a, b);
        // do smth with result
        res;
        return true;    // or false
    }
};

int main()
{
    bool res;
    res = wrapper<decltype(&A::f1), (void(*)(void))A::f1>::apply();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work on clang, getting `error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression` `note: cast that performs the conversions of a reinterpret_cast is not allowed in a constant expression`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like [this](http://ideone.com/Y0hZwb):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    static int f1(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int f2(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template <typename T, T X>
struct wrapper
{
    template <typename... Args>
    static bool value(Args... blargs)
    {
        return X(blargs...) == 3;
    }
};

int main()
{
    bool res;
    res = wrapper<decltype(&A::f1), &A::f1>::value(1,2);
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But seriously, this is so much easier:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool res;
    res = A::f1(a, b) == 3;
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could do that. But I won't be calling the function, I will register it by function pointer and then it will be called by Lua. So the function have to have specific signature with only 1 argument (my arguments will be passes through the Lua stack). At this point, I guess I'm just curious why free functions and static class functions behave totally different.